# FluentNhibernate WithTable vs Join

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to populate a property in a object via a joined table using FluentNHibernate.

I'm attempting to do exactly what this link outlines:
http://www.codeinsanity.com/2009/05/fluentnhibernate-mappings-join.html

The problem is I don't have WithTable as a available method in my mapping class.  My mapping class is defined like this:

```
public abstract class BaseObjectMap<TObject> : ClassMap<TObject> where TObject : BaseObject
```

So I guess my question is where is WithTable?

I also see references to using the Join method.  What is the difference between Join and WithTable?

Answer (score 3):

`WithTable` is what `Join` was called about 1.5 years ago.